# QListWidget::addItem() gives flickering when i call it 40 times per second

Tags: c++, performance, qt, logging

What is the choise better than QListWidget to display a lot of log lines in GUI that are coming from backend at average speed 40 lines per second?

QListWidget gives a flickering and even white box instead of a widget for a long time when a lot of strings are already placed into ListWidget.

Is there any better solution to dynamically display log lines to a user?

**update:**
Changed architecture. Adding *new QStrings* to std::deque< QString* >. Using QTimer i add that strings every 1/10 of second to QPlainTextEdit, deleting from deque. boost::mutex is used to protect std::deque (log lines are coming from different threads).

Would be nice to have a time to implement my own QListView and keep strings in big chunks of pre-allocated memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you need the functionalities of a `QListWidget`? If you just want to display log lines, I think a simple read-only [`QPlainTextEdit`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/main-snapshot/qplaintextedit.html) would be more appropriate.

Comment: I am afraid QPlainTextEdit may cause a lot of memory reallocations when i add lines. QListWidget looks appealing because of storing lines as a chain of separated lines :)

Comment: @pavelkolodin, with QListWidget you have all the overhead of Qt's MVC framework so it will definitely consume more memory than if you use plain text. It seems like you are trying to use a sledgehammer to crack a nut. At 40 lines per second anyway you'll need videogame-like optimizations to avoid flickering. Maybe try openGL or Direct 3D to implement your logger :)

Comment: @Laurent, Thank you. QPlainTextEdit much faster.

Answer (score 1):

You might try to use `QListView` and you own implementation of `QAbstractItemModel`. Then you can store your lines as you wish and append new lines in big groups (about every second should be ok). Then view is not refreshed at adding every line but only in groups, which should highly improve performace.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting a refresh rate and append all gathered items at once. You will avoid repaint of widget every line you append.

Long story short:
QTimer with refresh rate (~1-3 seconds would be enough), QListWidget::addItems instead of QListWidget::addItem

Comment: I already do use QTimer set to 100 ms for refreshing (-; Also changed QListWidget to QPlainTextEdit.